How can I populate the checkbox value to avoid check duplicates : React Native
Sorry, if that title is confusing. I've always been terrible at making title for these questions.
I have a list of images I am displaying from firebase. And I have a button to edit the list (add or remove more images). After the list is the way I want it. A save button to replace that prop in the db.
My problem is when I make a list and save it to the and I refresh to get my useEffect to get me my list back, and then I go to the checkboxes to add more, the checkboxes are all clear, so it lets me add one that has already been added before. If it was prepopulated (checked) then that would work
    // build the collection from selecting the checkboxes
const selectItem = (item, index) => {
  const newData = [...dropdowndata];
  const newItem = newData[index];

  newItem.checked = !item.checked;
  setChecked(!checked)
  setDropdownData(newData);    

  if (newItem.checked) {
    if (!gokyoNoWaza.includes(newItem)) {
      setGokyoNoWaza(prev => [...prev, newItem]); 
    }
  } else {
    setGokyoNoWaza(prev => prev.filter(i => i.title !== newItem.title));
  }
}

//set collection to data
const handleTestCollection = async () => {
  const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
  const docRef = doc(db, 'useraccounts', userId);
  
  const rokkyuData = [
    { gokyoNoWaza: Array.isArray(gokyoNoWaza) ? [...gokyoNoWaza] : [] },
  ];

  try {
    await setDoc(docRef, { rokkyu: rokkyuData }, { merge: true});
    console.log("Rokkyu Gokyo No Waza successfully updated!:", rokkyuData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
  }
}

//display the colleciton on load
useEffect(() => {
  const getUser = () => {        
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if(user) {      
        const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
        user !== null || user !== undefined
        const docRef = doc(db, 'useraccounts', userId);        

        getDoc(docRef).then((docSnap) => {
          const gokyoNoWazaData = docSnap.data().rokkyu?.find(item => item.gokyoNoWaza)?.gokyoNoWaza || [];
          if (docSnap.exists()){
            setGokyoNoWaza(gokyoNoWazaData);        
          } else {
            console.log("nothing here"); 
          }      
        });
      } 
    }); 
  }

  getUser();
}, [selectedwaza, gokyoNoWazaData]);

the checkbox, which is mapped inside a map function. That where item comes from.
<Checkbox.Item
    mode='android'
    color={activeColors.primary}
    status={item.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
    onPress={() => selectItem(item, index)}
/>


value=item.checked ? https://reactnative.dev/docs/checkbox#value

I knew it was something dumb I've done a million times :( Thanks bro

@ArleighHix actually no. It didn't work. value isnt a valid property of Checkbox in React Native Paper it uses status and I'm already evaluating the value there
